# Solving recursive functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I have come across this problem in [lecture slides](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs221/lectures/index.html#include=mdp1.js&slideId=dice-game&level=0) which i don't understand.

In a dice game there are 2 options:
1. play
2. stop

If we choose play, we get $4, and then roll the die. If the die rolls 1 or 2 we are forced to stop.

The slides show the expected earning (if you always choose play) from this game is $12. 
Specifically - I want to know how to compute the infinite recursive sum.

I think this is the model:

$$r_1 = (1/3)(4 * 1) + (2/3) (r_2)\\
r_2 = (1/3)(4 * 2) + (2/3) (r_3) \ldots\\
\ \\
E(r) = r_1 + r_2 + r_3 ....  = 12$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are guaranteed $4$ from the first roll.  The second is worth $\frac 23 \cdot 4$ because you have $\frac 23$ chance of doing it.  The third is $(\frac 23)^24$ and the $k$th is worth $(\frac 23)^{k-1}4$.  This gives you a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  Do you know how to sum those?

Comment: Yes.. makes sense now. Thank you.